# Jooq :Convert String to TableField Object?

Tags: java, jooq

I am using `JSON` to get data from db and my data looks like this i have saved JSON Object in db so in DB data is something like this

```
{"column":"\"someString\".\"Folder\".\"FolderCentury\"","ascending":true}
```

and i wrote below code to get data because its `JSON` Object

```
    JSONObject jsonObj = geodata.getJSONObject(i);
    TableField<Record, T> columnName = (TableField<Record, T>) jsonObj.get("column");
```

But here is the problem

```
 jsonObj.get("column");
```

this line return a String something like this

```
 (java.lang.String) "someString"."Folder"."FolderCentury"
```

But when i am doing casting its throw Exception

```
java.lang.ClassCastException: java.lang.String cannot be cast to org.jooq.TableField
```

I will want to know how can i Change `String` to `TableField` object? [TableField Interface](http://www.jooq.org/javadoc/latest/org/jooq/class-use/TableField.html)

Answer (score 1):

You may think that the JVM will "magically" know that your encoding of a jOOQ `TableField` to a JSON string literal implies that the inverse will be equally automatic. Obviously, this is not the case, and you will have to do some work yourself.

The simplest way I can see is to keep a lookup map between your encoding and the actual `TableField` instances.

```
Map<String, TableField<?>> lookup = new HashMap<>();

// SOME_STRING is the generated schema instance
for (Table<?> table : SOME_STRING.getTables()) {
    for (Field<?> field : table.fields()) {

        // Replace "toString()" by an actual SQL rendering call, if you prefer
        lookup.put(field.toString(), (TableField<?>) field);
    }
}
```

Comment: What it mean 'SOME_STRING.getTables()'  here you can check '{"column":"\"someString\".\"Folder\".\"FolderCentury\"","ascending":true}'   if you will see '"\"someString\".\"Folder\".\"FolderCentury\""' this is a 'String'

Comment: @Programmer: I know it's a string. But as I said, you cannot just cast strings to any type of object you happen to know. The computer cannot read your mind. Well, how did you produce that string?